# Adding/removing items from a list and then saving changes to MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Any recommendation or better a good script to add/remove items from a list and then saving the changes to MySQL?

Here is the think, in my web page I ask my users how many languages do they speak, I have a textfield and a add button, any time the user hits add, the language written in the textfield has to appear in a list, and it also needs to be removable. When the user finish the work, he hits a send button that do a simple POST/GET action to a PHP script.

This is 90% front-end work, and I'm not a front-end developer (I'm a PHP dev). I know that using some JavaScript/jQuery this can be done, but I don't have any idea of how to handle this.

I tried for a long time, searching some tutorials on internet, but I didn't find anything good. So, if you can provide me some help/tutorial/script I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need ajax for this if you are adding the languages all in one go.  You can just add hidden form fields to a list when the user clicks the add button and then remove them if they click remove.  This will make the interface much more responsive as well.  I threw together a quick example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wnFsE/

There really isn't much to the code to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be an AJAX call to your PHP file that would actually be editing your database. I would also include some sort of visual device to indicate if the database is being changed and once the changes have been saved.

The below example assumes this is being done via JSON.

```
function saveChanges() {

    var inputData = $('#your-input').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: inputData,
        url: '/file.php',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function ajaxSuccess(response) {
            // let the user know their changes are saved
        },
        failure: function ajaxFailure(response) {
            // let the user know something went wrong
        }
    });

};
```